# Kafka topic partitions with leader -1

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-topic

I noticed that few of my kafka topics are behaving in a manner i cannot explain clearly.

For eg:

```
./kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper ${ip}:2181 --topic test

Topic:test  PartitionCount:3    ReplicationFactor:1 Configs:retention.ms=1209600000
    Topic: test Partition: 0    Leader: 1   Replicas: 1 Isr: 1
    Topic: test Partition: 1    Leader: -1  Replicas: 2 Isr: 2
    Topic: test Partition: 2    Leader: 3   Replicas: 3 Isr: 3
```

I am particularly concerned about Partition: 1 which shows Leader '-1'.

I also notice that roughly 1/3 of the messages produced to this topic fail due to a 'Timeout'. This I believe is a consequence of one partition not having a leader.

I was wondering if anyone has insights into why this issue occurs and how to recover from this in a Production scenario without losing data?

**EDIT**:
I am using the librdkafka based python producer; and the error message I see is `Message failed delivery: KafkaError{code=_MSG_TIMED_OUT,val=-192,str="Local: Message timed out"}`

Comment: Is your second broker up and running? It would be useful if you could also post the error message for the timeout.

Comment: I edited the original post with the error message I receive. I have 3 node clustered broker, and it indeed looks like one of them is down.

However, producing/consuming to/from other topics (which do not have Leader: -1) seems to works as expected with failover.

Comment: "in a production scenario", you would have a replication factor of at least 3, and min in sync replicas setting in the producer of 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably your second kafka broker is down. 
In order to check active Kafka brokers you need to run

```
./zookeeper-shell.sh localhost:2181 <<< "ls /brokers/ids"
```

And the output should be similar to the one below:

```
Connecting to localhost:2181
Welcome to ZooKeeper!
JLine support is enabled

WATCHER::

WatchedEvent state:SyncConnected type:None path:null
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 0] ls /brokers/ids
[0, 1, 2]
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 1]
```

If the second broker is not listed in the active brokers then you need to figure out why is not up and running (logs should tell you if something went wrong). I would also suggest to increase the replication-factor since you have a multi-broker configuration.

Answer (score 1):

This often indicates that the broker leading that partition is offline. I would check the offline partitions metric to confirm this, but also check whether broker 2 is currently functional.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of kafka instead of -1, None is being used.
To see offline partitions  run the below command

```
./kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper <zookeeper_ip>:2181 --describe | grep "Leader: None"
```